# How to add flex project to rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I'm starting to learn in flex and ruby on rails.
I see some projects there is a flex folder under rails_project/app which
contains controller,
models, views. I think it's not mannually to add these folders to rails
project.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify an IDE this is tough to answer.

In Flash Builder, you may be able to right click on the project and "Add/Change Product Type" which would add a Flash Builder 'nature' to the project.

If all you need is access to the code; You could also add mapped directories to your rails project that point to your Flex source code located outside of the project root.  This wouldn't give you 'advanced' Flash Builder features such as compiling the project when you save Flex code, but it would make the code accessible from that project.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know it yet, you might wanna look into http://flexonrails.com/
where they offer a bunch of example applications and you can see the full source codes of both flex and rails side...